# PivotTable Calculated Field % formula

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a simple PivotTable that is just counting 1 column of data called "Conditions".
I have added "Conditions" (which is just text) to the "Rows", and the Value is a count of the "Conditions".

What I would now like to do is add a % column to the PivotTable using a fixed division of 2336, i.e. SUM(Conditions / 2336)
However, I can't get the formula to work using a calculated field, so that it's part of the PivotTable

It works if I add a formula manually to an adjacent row i.e. =GETPIVOTDATA("Conditions",$A$3,"Conditions",$A4)/2336
Then copy it down, but as it isn't linked to the PT, so when you collapse the PT data it stays static, and doesn't look right.

Is it possible to add the formula so that it for part of the PT and shows the % of conditions i.e. divided by 2336?

I'm using Excel 2010

[image]

Comment: Sample data would be helpful. What are you trying to sum? You cannot sum text, so it's a little unclear. Is the sum the sum of the count? Is that equal to the number of rows in your data?

Comment: The conditions are text that are counted. I need to create a % of the conditions, which is why I want to add a formula to divide the count of the conditions by 24. the yellow column is what I would like to create as part of the PT

Comment: Thanks for adding the data. Can you describe your formula in column C a bit more? For example, 286/24 is not equal to 0.61.

Comment: OK sorry for all the confusion. I have now attached the correct image as an example of what I would like to achieve i,e, the yellow column being part of the PT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add another column to your data and input a 1 for all rows. I titled this as "Count". Then your calculated field is simply Count/24.

[image]

Comment: OMG, you have done it regardless of all my confusion you knew what I needed (a helper column). Thank you so much.